# How to handle signal in MPI

Tags: c, signals, mpi

I am currently implementing a MPI program that will run in an infinite loop, the goal is when one of those processes receive the signal, all those processes will exit the infinite loop, there is a global variable flag that will indicate whether the signal is received, how can I use MPI_Allreduce to update all those flags value in each process? Here is part of my code:

```
int flag = 0;
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
        flag = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int count, id;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &count);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

    signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);
    while (true)
    {
         if (flag == 1)
         {
              break;
         }
    }
```

My confusion is that where should I add the MPI_Allreduce to update the flag value in all processes.